# NoSQL Comparison - Is this part of my Job?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata

For the more experienced Data Scientists here, i was asked to perform a case study on how Redis / HBase etc performs, compared to each other.How does data science play a role into this? Note that there will be no actual data involved.

Comment: I think Data Science career questions should be on topic here. If you are really asking whether this is a normal task, then you need to give more information about the role. There is sometimes a clue in the job title, e.g. Data Engineer is different to Data Scientist. However,  it's not consistent, plus in small teams you may be expected to cover a wide range of skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Redis, but as far as I understand the two are based on different principles and used for different things. Redis is in-memory while HBase is not. They are solutions to different problems. Maybe you should start by describing what kind of problems they are suitable for.